# Python Selenium upload images/files when input field not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

**Background:**

I administer an Amazon shop for a category that is unsupported by the Amazon bulk upload tool. The shop contains (once this question is resolved) +150 individual products with 6-9 preview images each and in 6 EU sites (huge manual upload effort).

I decided to use Selenium and my basic python skills to automate the upload.

**Problem:**

All works perfectly fine except for image upload. I had used this code in the past to send images into an input field:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]').send_keys('path/to/local/image')
```

Modifying this to fit to the image upload page in question:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('main_image_url').send_keys('path/to/local/image')
```

Returns a sea of red:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
>   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409710 (0c4084804897ac45b5ff65a690ec6583b97225c0),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)

**Also tried:**

I have read around a bit but my knowledge of Javascript is null so I have blindly tried a few javascript snippets to make the element visible first to no avail.

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("main_image_url").style.visibility = "visible";')
```

I've also read some solutions involving trying to navigate the actual dialogue window with complicated combinations of send_keys() but sound like trouble.

I'm on a Mac and using the Chrome driver.

Any tips much appreciated

**HTML element of page:**

[image: Screenshot from page. actual code below]

```html
<div id="main_image_url-wrapper" class="a-row a-spacing-medium input-container">
    <div data-attribute-name="main_image_url"
    data-image-index="0" class="a-row a-grid-vertical-align a-grid-center ilui-image-input-container image-not-selected hide-remove-button ilui-post-attribute">
        <input id="main_image_url" name="main_image_url"
        value="" cssClass="image-source-of-truth"
        type="hidden" autocomplete="off"
        />
        <div class="a-row">
            <label for="main_image_url" class="label">
            <span class="attribute-label-text">Main Image  
   <span class="a-size-base a-color-tertiary a-text-italic a-text-normal">
      (required)
   </span> </span> <span class="a-declarative"
                data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;attributeHelpmain_image_url&quot;,&quot;inlineContent&quot;:&quot;The URL where a main image of the product is located.  It&#39;s important that this is supplied for all products.&quot;}">                    
            <span class="help-icon"></span>                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="a-row ilui-image-wrapper ilui-visualization-element">
        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="image-select-main_image_url"
            data-image-select-main_image_url="{}"
            id="image-container-declarative">
            <div tabindex="0" class="ilui-image-select-container">
                <div id="image-camera-icon" class="icon-container">
                            <i class="icon"></i>
                     <ul class="a-nostyle a-vertical error-list image-error-list"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span> <img src="" class="ilui-img-thumbnail"
            />
            <div class="image-loading-overlay a-hidden">
                <div class="a-section upload-progress-meter image-progress-bar">
                    <div class="a-meter" aria-label="0%">
                        <div class="a-meter-bar"
                        style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    </div> <span class="percentage"></span>                    </div>
            </div> <span class="a-declarative" data-action="image-remove-button-main_image_url"
            data-image-remove-button-main_image_url="{}">
         <div tabindex="0" class="remove-image-button">
                
                    
                        <i class="a-icon a-icon-close"></i>
            </div>
     </span> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please format provided HTML please, it's hard to read and also elaborate your question actually what do you want, do you want to change image??

Comment: I am trying to upload images stored locally. I've wrestled with the html clean up of the embed tool here with no success. Any ideas on how to get nicely formatted HTML from the browser?

Comment: Go to Google and type online html code formatter and try any one these suggest website to beautify your then paste here. Thanks..

Comment: Code formatting a little better.